# how can I use styles for Django auth_views.LogoutView and auth_views.LoginView?

Tags: python, django

Styles for forms I can use widgets variable, but how can I use CSS styles for auth_views.LogoutView and  auth_views.LoginView?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the extra argument `template_name`  to the view from your urls and in this template you can use your custom styles.

```
  path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='you_html.html'),name = 'login')
```